# Python auto completing directory when I press tab (./)

Tags: python, macos, autocomplete, tabs, terminal

I have a rather peculiar problem, when i'm working on Python in Max OSX terminal, my tab key no longer indents, it now inserts a ./

It seems it is auto-completing directories, if I press tab twice it lists directories, if i type in part of a directory and press tab it autocompletes. I understand this is a standard function in terminal, but not supposed to happen in the Python interpreter? The same thing happens when I run Python in x11.

I have no idea what I did to cause this, the change seemed to happen while I was in Python's help function. I may have pressed a certain combination of keys to activate it, but have no idea what it was. Furthermore google searches aren't returning anyone with the same issue.

I would really appreciate some help here, I'm a beginning computer science student and not being able to tab in Python is pretty frustrating :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug; see [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue9907) for details.  Most likely you are using the Python 2.7 from the python.org OS X 32-bit/64-bit installer for 10.5 and above or you are using a Python 2.7 or 3.2alpha built from source.  If you are using 2.7, the easiest workaround is to install the other [python.org OS X installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/): the one for 32-bit for 10.3 and above.

UPDATE: The fix for this problem is included as of the Python 2.7.2 and the 3.2 python.org installers and, apparently, in Apple's 2.7.1 system Python in OS X 10.7.

Comment: Thanks for answering :). You're right, I did install the 10.5+ version, and noticed the problem shortly afterwards. Also when I launch python2.6 from terminal the bug is gone. Unfortunately installing the 10.3+ version didn't fix the bug. Should installing it automatically overwrite the other installation or do I need to manually do something?

Comment: With the 2.7 10.3 version, /usr/local/bin/python2.7 should no longer exhibit the directory auto-complete.  If you want it to autocomplete Python commands, you do need to import the rlcompleter module, preferably automatically, as described here: http://docs.python.org/library/rlcompleter.html

Comment: I understand, but the 10.3 version of python is not being launched when I type in python in terminal. It seems that although I most recently installed the 10.3 version, the default version is still the 10.5+ version. Can I make terminal launch the 10.3 version by default? For now I've just been launching python2.6

Comment: Try removing the Python framework first, then run the 10.3 installer again. In a terminal shell:
`sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`